# Does NetLogo have the same or similar functions as the bigdecimal function existing in Java?

Tags: java, netlogo, bigdecimal

Does NetLogo have the same or similar functions as the bigdecimal function existing in Java? If it does not exist in NetLogo, is there any other good way? I'd like to ask your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no, it does not.

If you *really* need big decimals, however, you could write an extension to manipulate them.

I might be mistaken, but as far as I know, there isn't such an extension out there at the moment and I think it could be a valuable addition to the NetLogo ecosystem.

See the [Extensions API guide](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API) for more information on how to write your own extension.